# jomsocial profile update in adminpanel causes issue

Tags: php, joomla, phpbb

I am using Joomla1.5, jomsocial and phpBB3.

I have a problem with the jomsocial profile update in adminpanel.

```
    * phpbb3 Username Update:
    * phpbb3: A user has been found that matches the login details
    * phpbb3: Skipped Password Update: Clear text password not available
    * phpbb3: Language of the user not updated
```

Please help me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I dont know why experts hurry to give negative mark to new users. New users are usually unaware of many things. But I dont know what such experts want to prove

Comment: @Awais It's not really a programming question